# MacPorts, how to run "post-destroot" script

Tags: macos, macports, gdb

I'm trying to install MacPorts gdb; it seems to be poorly supported…

Running "port install" installs it to `/opt/local/libexec/gnubin/gdb`, but the intent doesn't seem to be to add that to `$PATH`. The [portfile](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/devel/gdb/Portfile) doesn't define any parameters for `port select` which is typically used to set a MacPorts installation to handle default Unix commands. But it does include these lines:

```
foreach binary [glob -tails -directory ${destroot}${prefix}/bin g*] {
    ln -s ${prefix}/bin/${binary} ${destroot}${prefix}/libexec/gnubin/[string range $binary 1 end]
}
```

This is buried under an action labeled `post-destroot`.  `destroot` is a MacPorts command but `post-destroot` is not. The script is apparently not run by `port install` or `port activate`, or if it's failing it's doing so silently.

Is there a better approach than creating the links manually?

Comment: I suggest that you try debugging something with MacPorts gdb first. There is a high probability you won't be able to debug with MacPorts gdb at all.

Comment: @Paul Huh, previously when I upgraded by building from source the instructions at http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin worked for the code signing issue, but now it doesn't. Hmmmmm, I'm sure there's a solution for that, though.

Comment: If you find the solution, please share. I hate using outdated gdb 6.3 w/o tui, but wasn't able to make new gdb work.

Comment: @Paul Will do. By the way, this question turned out to be a non-issue; I've answered myself below.

Answer (score 0):

Woops, the binary was already installed as `ggdb`. Guess I misunderstood the `glob` command. However, as Paul noted in comments above, it still doesn't actually work.